# Laravel 5.3 Method distinct does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, distinct

I am trying to write a query that returns the count of distinct links.  However, I keep on getting

> Method distinct does not exist

Here is my code

```
$sample = Sample::all();
$uniqueResumes = $sample->distinct()->select('link')->count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this :

```
$uniqueResumes = Sample::select('link')->distinct()->count();
```